# Need of ISA Server (Reverse Proxy) for ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, proxy, hosting, firewall, isaserver

Our company has its own servers for our asp.net applications (ASP.NET 2.0 applications with WCF services) with an ISA Server as Reverse Proxy and Firewall in front of it. We want to run the asp.net applications on external servers at hosting companies (in germany). There are several hosting companies, but we couldn't find one with ISA Server as Reverse Proxy and Firewall.

The web applications (with SQL Server) contains sensitive data (like medical patient data) and needs a high security environment.

Nevertheless **is an ISA Server essential for such web applications?** And if yes, is there **any alternative?** We tried a hoster with apache as Reverse proxy but had several problems. Which **disadvantages** could raise without a reverse proxy and external firewall (belonging **security and performance**)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This obviously depends on how confidential and secure you wish the web site to be.

From the sounds of things, I would say you should be using ISA Server, or the next version which is called Threat Management Gateway.

To host this, all you need is a provider who can offer hosting of entire machines or virtual machines (managed hosting). I would be quite surprised if there aren't dozens of these companies in Germany.
Any of these providers should be able to install TMG on a server, configure it correctly, and host your websites behind it.

For example: http://www.rackspace-hosting.de/managed-hosting/hosting-solutions/dedicated-servers/

Comment: this is correct. I forgot to note that we searched virtual solutions for financial reasons. what could be the cons to not use an isa and are there alternatives? thanks.

Comment: An isa server is just one part of a security system, so it really depends on your requirements. A con might be lowering your security, which might lead to loss of information. I'm not aware of any alternatives in the Microsoft area, There are other systems which do the same thing... IBM's Tivoli Access manager (i'm not sure if it still exists), Oblix, which is now owned by Oracle, or squid.